# need to store IP address, is Request.UserHostAddress ok to use?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In a website I need to store visitor's IP address for security logging. I m not sure about IP address and its details just have an idea there are different types of IP addresses like user, internet provider, LAN IP, WAN IP etc.

I am even not sure which IP address I should store in database for security I have searched and came to know about `Request.UserHostAddress` that it returns The IP address of the remote client.

Can you please guide and confirm if I am sotring correct IP and using correct code to retrive IP ?

**Edit**
I am not certain why IP address is stored but know just as a good practice to do it. My guess is IP need to be stored to identify user, just in case if something wrong happens, with stored IP address it can be traced out who did it or from what area this request came.

Is there some other use of IP, please direct me as well.

Cheers

Comment: You need to find out what is actual requirement for "security logging" - `UserHosAddress` is more or less all you can get, but it is not necessary relates to/identifies user due to proxies/NATs.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov can you please see my edit and reply. Thanks

Comment: ??? you have very conflicting statements in your post "I need to store visitor's IP address for security logging" and "I am not certain why IP address is stored". You have to decide / learn yourself what are **your** security requirements. Maybe you even need to consult with lawyer...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I really appriciate your reply, thanks for it. As I explained I am not sure how it will work but I also explained what is my understanding. If I wrong please correct me, kindly also guide me what I am not aware of as I am not aware of and want to learn.

Answer (score 2):

IP stands for Internet Protocol, which is the protocol underlying HTTP, which is what clients use to connect to web servers. Every machine on an IP network has a unique IP address.

`UserHostAddress` is the correct property for identifying the client's IP address. It does not matter whether the client is coming from the LAN or WAN, nor does it matter who their internet provider is. Internet providers (and I'm simplifying here) help route traffic to your website, but don't actually participate as an endpoint; the ISP's servers will not show up in the `UserHostAddress`, only the actual client who *initiates* the connection, which is *typically* the user.

Note that I say *typically*. IP addresses can be spoofed, or they can be hidden behind a proxy (like TunnelBear) or other obfuscation system (like Tor). There's no way to guarantee that you have the "real" IP address of the "real" user, but the aforementioned property is the closest you're going to be able to get.

Comment: thanks, can you please see my edit as well.

If there is no way to guarantee that I am getting real IP, then in general why IP is stored ? Acutualy I am not clear about that but just know as a good practice it should be stored. Help please.

Comment: +1 Also I think "typically" is a stretch - i.e. most home users/organizations are behind some sort of NAT/proxy. I'm not sure if phones obtain direct IP.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, what would be solution please ? What is your recommendation ? Not to store IP at all ? If store what would be the best case to proceed. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @haansi - `UserHostAddress` is the solution (maybe along with `forwarded-for` header) to get more-or-less all available information about client. It is up to you to find out what is exactly your requirement and is this solves it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Organizations yes, home users definitely not; lots of them may be behind wifi routers and such, but that detail isn't really important to webmasters - it's a "household" and that's precise enough.